# Laravel 5. Посоветуйте библиотеку для реализации сервиса подписок

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу использовать полуготовые решения или посмотреть на их архитектуру. Система подписок: пользователь получает кредиты, за кредиты имеет возможность разрешить что-то сделать (получить какой-либо ресурс сайта, посетить выбранное событие).
Буду благодарен за подсказки.

Comment: я может чего не знаю, но это слишком специфичная библиотека получается. Такую проще самому под себя написать

Comment: Действительно это целый сайт описали, а не библиотеку

Comment: Точно такой же системы с кредитами нету. Но пример хорошо реализованной системы подписок через Stripe (не работает с СНГ) вы можете посмотреть здесь: https://github.com/laravel/cashier это офф. библиотека. Она реализует обычный функционал подписок.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл такое решение:

- для разделения на роли и права: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust
- для системы подписок: https://github.com/rinvex/subscriptions